# Bash copy variable containing array as reference

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, reference

With the following code I can copy an array content to another one so that when altering one array the other is untouched.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ARRAY_A=(a b c d e)
ARRAY_B=("${ARRAY_A[@]}")

echo "Before removal:"

printf "%s " ${ARRAY_A[@]}
echo
printf "%s " ${ARRAY_B[@]}
echo

echo
echo "After removal:"
unset ARRAY_A[0]

printf "%s " ${ARRAY_A[@]}
echo
printf "%s " ${ARRAY_B[@]}
echo
```

Prints:

```
Before removal:
a b c d e 
a b c d e 

After removal:
b c d e 
a b c d e
```

Is it possible to copy the reference to that array instead, so that when altering one array the "other" (which is the same then) appears to be changed as well (like below)?

```
Before removal:
a b c d e 
a b c d e 

After removal:
b c d e 
b c d e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes? Just use a bash name reference.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ARRAY_A=(a b c d e)
declare -n ARRAY_B=ARRAY_A

echo "Before removal:"

printf "%s " "${ARRAY_A[@]}"
echo
printf "%s " "${ARRAY_B[@]}"
echo

echo
echo "After removal:"
unset ARRAY_A[0]

printf "%s " "${ARRAY_A[@]}"
echo
printf "%s " "${ARRAY_B[@]}"
echo
```

Note: prefer to use lowercase variables in your scripts. Upper case variables are by convention meant to be exported variables, like COLUMN, LINES, PWD, UID, IFS, etc.